# Project names lead to namespace confusion

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a couple of WPF projects that fail to compile due to error **The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace**. Here is a minimum reproducible sample.

There is a class library called **Wpf.Lib** where I define a class called WindowBase.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Wpf.Lib.Controls
{
   public class WindowBase : Window
   {
   }
}
```

Then, I have this app project called **Samples.Wpf.Demo**, where I have a reference to **Wpf.Lib**.

[image]

I want `WindowBase` to be the base of my windows in this project. I have one window called `MainWindow`. The C# code is as follows:

```
using Wpf.Lib.Controls;

namespace Samples.Wpf.Demo
{
   public partial class MainWindow : WindowBase
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}
```

The XAML for this window is as follows:

```
<controls:WindowBase
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Wpf.Lib.Controls;assembly=Wpf.Lib"
        x:Class="Samples.Wpf.Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Samples.Wpf.Demo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</controls:WindowBase>
```

The error that I am getting is:

> MainWindow.g.cs(42,43,42,46): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Lib' does not exist in the namespace 'Samples.Wpf' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)

MainWindow.g.cs looks like this:

```
using Wpf.Lib.Controls;

namespace Samples.Wpf.Demo {

    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Wpf.Lib.Controls.WindowBase, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
    }
}
```

I think the compiler gets confused because it finds Wpf.Lib and then it has Samples.Wpf and assumes there is a Samples.Wpf.Lib. How do I fix this, other than changing the namespaces, which is something I would prefer not to do for reasons (part of a larger library and I want consistent namespaces). I tried extern aliases but that didn't help.

Comment: `MainWindow.g.cs` is auto-generated from `MainWindow.xaml`. Any attempt to edit it is futile because as soon as you compile again your changes are overwritten.